# Get SamAccountname from LDAP using PHP

Tags: php, ldap

Ldap Authentication works. I just want to get the samaccountname from Ldap using php.  I can get the users email, and OU and display name, but is there a way to get the SamAccountName?

I'm using this:

```
if (@!$loginldap = ldap_bind($ds, "$username@$ldap_domain", $password)) { 
  if ($loginldap) { // if binding to ldap works
   $attributes = array("displayname", "mail");
   $filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$username))";
   $result = ldap_search($ds, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attributes);
   $entries = ldap_get_entries($ds, $result);
  }
}
```

and the $entries array contains all the stuff I need except for SamAccountName.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly request the samaccountname. Add it to the attributeList

```
$attributes = array("displayname", "mail", "samaccountname");
```

and do the search.

Comment: :) happens sometime for everyone.

Comment: just want to add that it must be in lowercase on linux (haven't tested it on windows)

Comment: I have related question , i am beginner though . ....If there are subdomains (childa,abc.com childb.abc.com, childc.abc.com )and contains same samaccountname(123456789) how the AD is gonna do authentication ?? Is it going to check the subdomains one by one so that user can be authenticated ?? my app uses only samaccountname as login id. What is the password is different for this samaccount in each of the subdomain... ??